# Динамическая кнопка на php

Tags: php, битрикс

Сайт работает на Битриксе, нужно сделать динамическую кнопку с тремя позициями:

1. состояние покоя
2. состояние при наведении мышки
3. состояние во время нажатия

Вся инфа, которую могу найти, касается только CSS. Спасибо всем, кто отзовется!

Answer (score 4):

PHP - не язык разметки, и интерфейс с помощью него не сделаешь.
Копай в сторону JavaScript и CSS.

Answer (score 4):

А почему средства CSS не устраивают? Если сайт не расчитан под  iOS и Android, то псевдоклассы нормально решают вашу задачу.

```
a:link    { color: red }    /* не посещенная ссылка */
a:visited { color: blue }   /* посещенная ссылка   */
a:hover   { color: yellow } /* при наведении     */
a:active  { color: lime }   /* при нажатии    */
```

Answer (score 3):

Вот элементарный пример:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Кнопка</title>
<style>
#button{
absolute;
top: 5px;
left: 5px;
width: 60px;
height: 20px;
text-align: center;
background-color: #FFFF00;
border-radius: 5px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="button">Кнопка</div>
<script>
var button=document.getElementById("button");
button.onmouseover=function(){button.style.backgroundColor="#FF00FF";}
button.onmouseout=function(){button.style.backgroundColor="#FFFF00";}
button.onmousedown=function(){button.style.backgroundColor="#FF0000";}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```